# Global npm packages are install on different user directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-config

Recently I have created a new user on Windows 10 and removed the old user, after that when I try adding an global npm package it get installed on the previous user %appdata%/Roaming directory. I'm not able to use those global libs now.

Say for example

```
npm install -g gulp
```

installs the gulp module under

> C:\Users<DELETED_USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp

and not found in the new user directory

> C:\Users<NEW_USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp

Is there any npm config I have to touch to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the following command:

```
npm config get prefix
```

it probably prints:

> `C:\Users\<DELETED_USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\`

If that's the case, i.e. it references the pathname to the *<DELETED_USER>*, then consider utilizing the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-config) command to change the [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#prefix) value. E.g.

```
npm config set prefix "C:\Users\<NEW_USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm"
```

If you also run the following command:

```
run npm config ls -l
```

you may find other configuration properties (e.g. [`cache`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#cache)) whose values contain the *<DELETED_USER>* pathname in them too. For those also consider setting them as necessary using: `npm config set <key> <value>`